# The docker image build is stuck

Tags: windows, docker, containers

I need to build a windows docker image for a window app on windows 10 with docker desktop installed on vm, but when the build process is stuck when running the installation of this app. the log looks like something bellow,

```
PS C:\docker> docker image build . -t app
Sending build context to Docker daemon  144.1MB
Step 1/6 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8
 ---> 9b87edf03093
Step 2/6 : COPY . /app
 ---> ac4b1124d856
Step 3/6 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in cf4bd2345d26
Removing intermediate container cf4bd2345d26
---> d4f28097afd9
Step 4/6 : RUN .\ELSA1.0_2.6.6.243.exe
---> Running in b9356f975aa6
(And the process is stuck for several hours here and is terminated by me)
```

the docker file is

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8 # this is a base image because asp.net 3.5 is a prerequisite for the app

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN .\ELSA1.0_2.6.6.243.exe # I am stuck here!
```

I have tried to do something in the base image like so, but it seems that I cannot do anything

```
PS C:\docker> docker container run  -it 
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8

 Service 'w3svc' has been stopped

 Service 'w3svc' started
```

Are there any good ideas to debug this issue? By the way the installer can work normally on windows 10.

Comment: make the step as `CMD ELSA1.0_2.6.6.243.exe`

Comment: It doesn't stuck. thanks a lot. But the image cannot run. the error is PS C:\docker> docker run thisimage

 Service 'w3svc' has been stopped

APPCMD failed with error code 13

Failed to update IIS configuration

Comment: then that is somthing in your `App`

Comment: Are you using any AV like Symantec Endpoint protection? I've faced issues with it on Windows Server 2016. Check this out : https://support.symantec.com/us/en/article.tech246815.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never execute the command in the `RUN` statement that not terminate. I see in Docker build logs that you started `exe` file in `RUN` command. This will keep stuck your docker build process and will wait for `SIGINT`. The same will happen like if you execure `RUN npm start` so it will hang the build process.

Add your executable at entrypoint or CMD.

Another thing that can be the issue in such cased

**Considerations for using CMD with Windows**

> On Windows, file paths specified in the CMD instruction must use
>   forward slashes or have escaped backslashes \. The following are
>   valid CMD instructions:

`dockerfile`

```
# exec form

CMD ["c:\\Apache24\\bin\\httpd.exe", "-w"]

# shell form

CMD c:\\Apache24\\bin\\httpd.exe -w
```

You can further read about Window CMD [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/manage-windows-dockerfile)

However, the following format without the proper slashes will not work:

dockerfile

```
CMD c:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe -w
```